# Vim: Ack.vim and AsyncRun conflict over quickfix window

Tags: vim

In my Vim configuration I have both *Ack.vim* and *AsyncRun* plugins. Both plugins, at least by default, output to a `quickfix` window. This is an issue for me because I need to have *Ack.vim* results open, and then execute *AsyncRun* commands while processing those results. But once *AsyncRun* is executed, it overwrites *Ack.vim* results with its output, so I have to re-run same `:Ack` search to get next search results displayed.

Example: my workflow often includes search with `:Ack`, after which I modify one file from the results, write the file, then modify the file from the next result, and so on. However, I also have `autocmd BufWritePost` configuration which runs an *AsyncRun* (e.g. JS `prettier` or Python's `yapf`) when a buffer is written. Thus, once I modify the first file and write the buffer, output from *Ack.vim* gets replaced by the output from *AsyncRun*.

Is there a way to either:

- use `location-list` for either of the *Ack.vim* or *AsyncRun*, instead of the `quickfix` window?
- or have two `quickfix` windows at the same time, each for each of the plugins' outputs?
- or, even suppress *AsyncRun* output and not open the `quickfix` at all for it? (in my case, when running `yapf` or `prettier`, I don't really need to study their output at all)

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at Ack.vim's documentation. There are a bunch of other commands, such as `:LAck`, which populates the location list rather than the quickfix list.

The quickfix window is global, so you can only have one at a time. But you can always navigate to the previous and next quickfix list with `:cprevious` and `:cnext`. The location-list on the other hand is per window.

I suggest to skim through the quickfix and location-list documentation with `:help quickfix`.